# Can't add user location button on an iOS 6 map

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, mkmapview

I'm developing an application that uses an iOS 6 MKMap view and I would like to enable the "user location button" (the one that you see at the bottom-left of the screen when you are using the Maps application). 
I didn't find anything that could help me so I've tried to make this button myself with this code:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D currentCoordinates;
    currentCoordinates.latitude = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    currentCoordinates.longitude = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;

    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(currentCoordinates, _mapView.region.span);
    [_mapView setRegion:viewRegion animated:YES];
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

}

- (IBAction)moveToCurrentLocation:(id)sender {
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

So when I press the button the locationManager updates user's current location and the map changes it's region with a new one centered on user's current location and with the same span.
Now I have another problem: when I press the button the maps moves to the right coordinates but it also zooms out (in other words the span increases) even if I crete a new region with the old span.
I can't understand this behavior, I would like to preserve the old span as the Map app does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That button on maps is toggling the `userTrackingMode` property on the mapView, so set it to one of these:

```
MKUserTrackingModeNone //nothing, normal map view
MKUserTrackingModeFollow //user is highlighted and stays centered on map when you move
MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading //you get the heading as well, so your direction is up on the map
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the official iOS button for that, this code will add it to your UIToolbar and connect it to your mapview

```
UIBarButtonItem *trackingButton = [[MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem alloc] initWithMapView:self.mapView];
NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.toolbar.items];
[items addObject:trackingButton];
[self.toolbar setItems:items];
```